# Can I create a function which accepts a pointer to an array which may contain a different type of numbers on each call?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I need to write a function which writes an array of "n" elements to a binary output file. I would like to avoid having to write a separate function for each type of data I may wish to write (int, float, double, etc).

Is there any way I can specify the data type (perhaps number-of-bytes) as an argument to the function, and let the function determine how it handles it?

e.g.

```
f_writebinary(??? *data, int size, long n) {

   for(i=0;i<n;i++) {

        fwrite((data+i),size,1,stdout); 

    }
}
```

...or is this a totally absurd thing to expect of C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what `fwrite()` is. It uses a `const void *` which means "pointer to any type of data", and treats it as a pointer to bytes.

So, your wrapper isn't really needed, you can just make a correctly-sized call to `fwrite()` right away to write the array:

```
const int my_ints[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
const double my_doubles[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

fwrite(my_ints, sizeof *my_ints, sizeof my_ints / sizeof *my_ints, stdout);
fwrite(my_doubles, sizeof *my_doubles, sizeof my_doubles / sizeof *my_doubles, stdout);
```

Note that writing binary data to `stdout` can be somewhat rude, and also that I/O calls should be checked for errors.

If you drop the "x elements of y bytes" model that `fwrite()`'s API uses, and just treat them as single chunks of bytes, you can simplify the calls:

```
fwrite(my_ints, sizeof my_ints, 1, stdout);
fwrite(my_doubles, sizeof my_doubles, 1, stdout);
```

Note that there's no point in looping, the numbers in each array will be adjacent in memory so `fwrite()` can write them all at once. It's generally best to keep the number of I/O calls done down as much as possible, so if you can do a single write of `n * m` bytes instead of `n` writes of `m` bytes each, that's almost often better. Remember that that many of the underlying devices that you write to are block-oriented, and will benefit a lot from getting whole blocks of data since that's what they have to write, anyway.

Comment: Very happy but almost too cynical to believe it could be that simple :) - I do need the wrapper though, for other reasons (particular headers need to be included to define the dimensions in the array for other programs reading the file, etc.)

Comment: Question: I guess fwrite doesn't need the loop because it handles buffering itself - the main reason for the loop was to write in chunks for speed. Do you know if this is a safe assumption across Linux builds and compilers?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `???` with `char`. Or use `void` and cast to `char*` inside the function, so there is no need to cast to `char*` when calling the function. And better use `size_t` instead of `int` and `long`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...

size_t f_writebinary(void * data, size_t size, size_t n) 
{
  size_t result = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
  {    
    size_t result_inner = fwrite(((char *) data) + (i * size), size, 1, stdout); 
    if (!result_inner)
    {
      /* handle error here */
    }
    else
    {
      ++result;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Optimised version:

```
size_t f_writebinary(void * data, size_t size, size_t n) 
{
  size_t result = 0;

  n *= size;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += size) 
  {    
    size_t result_inner = fwrite(((char *) data) + i, size, 1, stdout); 
    if (!result_inner)
    {
      /* handle error here */
    }
    else
    {
      ++result;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

To cut it short: Just mimik the signature `fwrite()` uses.